# How do I display a different HTML attribute value in a Django template based on whether a mobile device is used?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to change the href in a template depending on whether a certain condition is satisfied (the user is viewing the page on a mobile device).  If the user is using a regular device, the URL would be

```
{{ articlestat.article.path }}
```

Otherwise the path would be the above, except wiht the "www." replaced by "mobile.".  What's the right way to do this?  I have the below

```
{% if request.user_agent.is_mobile %}
             <td align="center"><a href="{{ articlestat.article.path }}" target="_blank">Read Article</a></td>
{% else %} 
             <td align="center"><a href="{{ articlestat.article.mobile_path }}" target="_blank">Read Article</a></td> 
{% endif %}
```

but it seems a little lengthy and I'm thinking there's a more concise way in Django to write all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a `Django` way of going about this at first glance but I do have a quick `Javascript` solution that you can have much more control over.

```
function redirect(btn, url) {
    btn.on('click', function () {
      window.location.href = url; // A string
    })
}

var btn = <your btn>; // Use JQuery to get element as an ID
var url = <redirect url>;
redirect(btn, url);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  My challenge is coming up wiht a Django expression for the "<redirect url>" portion of what you have above.